# После перевода сайта на другой сервер перестали открываться страницы блога

Tags: wordpress, nginx

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Буду благодарен за любую подсказку в каком направлении копать.
Проблема возникла после смены хостинга. Так же ввиду смены хостинга решил заодно отказаться от apache, оставив сайта на одном nginx.
Сам сайт работает на joomla, на сайте блог работает на wordpress. Сайт перевелся успешно, все работает, проблема с постами блога. Страницы блога по адресу site.ru/blog открывается, админка блога по адресу https://site.ru/blog/wp-admin/ так же работает, но ссылки на все посты выдают 404 ошибку.
Ссылка имеет вид https://site.ru/blog/nazvanie-posta/
wordpress 5.5
php 5.6
nginx version: nginx/1.17.10
Буду благадарен за любую наводку

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561

Comment: Ознакомился с материалом ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561.
Там в основном проблемы идут в случае смены названия домена, расположения, протокола. У меня данные параметры без изменений. Попробовал так же рекомендуемый плагин миграции WP Migrate DB. Результат остался тот же. Блог и сайт работают, посты - не открываются. 
Имеются еще какие предположения?

Comment: 404 кто выдает joomla или wp?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/

Comment: 404 выдает wp, вернее ссылки на непосредственно посты и категории. Блог работает на wp. Админка wp открывается, главная блога  ( wp)  же открывается

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему по статье https://nginxlibrary.com/wordpress-permalinks/
Добавил блок в конфигурацию nginx

```
location /blog/ {
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
```

}

Спасибо SeVlad за подсказки и наводку!